# RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars stop execution of code

Tags: python, runtime-error, anaconda

When I try to execute this block of code
I am using jupyter notebook

```
for i in range(0,train_len):
    avg = (x1[i] + x2[i] + x3[i] + x4[i])/4
    h = x0*w0 + x1[i]*w1 + x2[i]*w2 + x3[i]*w3 + x4[i]*w4  
    error = avg - h
    w0 = w0 + n*error
    w1 = w1 + n*x1[i]*error
    w2 = w2 + n*x2[i]*error
    w3 = w3 + n*x3[i]*error
    w4 = w4 + n*x4[i]*error
```

this encountered this error

```
C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  """
C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:6: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  import sys
C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

C:\Users\Md. Arif Ahmed\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Something looks very broken here. You may need to reinstall Anaconda

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using anaconda

Comment: Anaconda is not an IDE, it's a distribution of Python. Spyder would be an IDE for Anaconda. It's possible that you have done something like divide by 0 in your code and it's blown up, but that traceback doesn't look normal to me.

Comment: You can't use the read and write procedures at the same time! You cannot begin a second operation without checking the integrity of the data in the first transaction. The delay of the process must be great for the source and destination to be the same. A specific transition is mandatory for RAM and CPU address allocation. Computers also make mistakes.